# Optimization of virtual table lookups

Tags: c++, compilation, compiler-optimization

With code like below, can a compiler tell that `a` is in fact an instance of `B` and optimize away the virtual table lookup?

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
  public:
    virtual void f()
    {
        std::cout << "A::f()" << std::endl;
    }
};

class B : public A
{
  public:
    void f()
    {
        std::cout << "B::f()" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    A* a = &b;
    a->f();

    return 0;
}
```

Additional question after the answers of Jonthan Seng and reima: In case gcc is used, would it be necessary to use any flags to force it to optimize the vtable lookup?

Comment: The only way to find out for sure is to look at the assembly. But yes, devirtualization is a standard compiler optimizations.

Comment: Just added disassembly for GCC.  I used the `-O1` flag for basic optimizations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) can easily make this optimization, and even inlines the function call. This can be seen from the generated assembly:

```
Dump of assembler code for function main():
   0x0000000000400500 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x0000000000400501 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000400504 <+4>: mov    $0x40060c,%edi
   0x0000000000400509 <+9>: xor    %al,%al
   0x000000000040050b <+11>:  callq  0x4003f0 <printf@plt>
   0x0000000000400510 <+16>:  xor    %eax,%eax
   0x0000000000400512 <+18>:  pop    %rbp
   0x0000000000400513 <+19>:  retq
```

I took the liberty of replacing `std::cout << …` by equivalent calls to `printf`, as this greatly reduces the clutter in the disassembly.

GCC 4.6 can also deduce that no vtable lookup is needed, but does not inline:

```
Dump of assembler code for function main():
   0x0000000000400560 <+0>: sub    $0x18,%rsp
   0x0000000000400564 <+4>: mov    %rsp,%rdi
   0x0000000000400567 <+7>: movq   $0x4007c0,(%rsp)
   0x000000000040056f <+15>:  callq  0x400680 <B::f()>
   0x0000000000400574 <+20>:  xor    %eax,%eax
   0x0000000000400576 <+22>:  add    $0x18,%rsp
   0x000000000040057a <+26>:  retq
```

Comment: +1 Visual Studio 2010 also devirtualizes it. But it does not inline it.

Comment: I have only gcc 4.4 at the moment. It doesn't seem to optimize the lookup even with -O3:  
    subq $24, %rsp  
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32  
    movq $_ZTV1B+16, (%rsp)  
    movq %rsp, %rdi  
    call *_ZTV1B+16(%rip)  
    xorl %eax, %eax  
    addq $24, %rsp  
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8  
   ret

Comment: @Ruup, know that feel bro.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe it can -- that would depend on the smarts of the compiler and the optimization requirements.

But, this is one call.  Why do you care about optimizing this one call?  And, if you do care, why not just get the type right for this one call?

The first answer to all questions about optimization is, "Why do you need to optimize that?"  Have a performance tool report saying 50% of the application time is one place, and the question is answered.  "Oh, but its inefficient," the most common answer, leads to unmaintainable code that rarely optimizes the code that is actually inefficient.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but if the OP didn't care, this question wouldn't have been asked.

Comment: People quite often care about optimization when there is no reason to.   So, I'm going to make a question out of it.

Comment: It's just to make an example as simple as possible and to understand what compilers can or cannot do.

Comment: "People quite often care about optimization when there is no reason to" Is it your answer to all questions about optimization? I can assure you that there are cases when the difference between a function being virtual or not is important.

Comment: @piokuc: Right, the question is whether this is one of them.

Comment: I've seen differences of up to 30% in actual code. So don't think it never matters. In this case, the OP has obviously simplified it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Not the simplified example, but I can easily imagine the same question in a context of processing gigabytes of data coming from large hadron collider, a satellite or something like that